# Exclude specific user id or user role during echoing get_the_author_meta

Tags: php, wordpress

I have used the following code to list users with avatars, name and a custom user meta:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url($q->ID);?>" target="_blank">  
<?php echo get_avatar( $q->ID, 150 ); ?> 
<?php echo get_the_author_meta('display_name', $q->ID);?><br />
<?php if (get_the_author_meta('bb_user_honey', $q->ID) != '') : ?>
<?php echo get_the_author_meta('bb_user_honey', $q->ID); ?>
<?php endif; ?></a>
```

Any idea how I can exclude a specific User ID or a specific User Role - for example the admin roles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function for that :)

You should use [get_users](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) to retrieve users, you can easily apply filters on it and then, loop on the array returned to display what you want.

From the docs :

```
  <?php get_users( $args ); ?> 
Parameters

<?php $args = array(
    'blog_id'      => $GLOBALS['blog_id'],
    'role'         => '',
    'meta_key'     => '',
    'meta_value'   => '',
    'meta_compare' => '',
    'meta_query'   => array(),
    'include'      => array(),
    'exclude'      => array(),
    'orderby'      => 'login',
    'order'        => 'ASC',
    'offset'       => '',
    'search'       => '',
    'number'       => '',
    'count_total'  => false,
    'fields'       => 'all',
    'who'          => ''
 ); ?>
```

Then you got an array with users in it, loop on it to get name, id, mail etc...

NB: if you want to display avatar you can use http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_avatar

**EDIT :** Here is a example to get all authors of the blog and show their name & avatar. Read the doc i give you upper to be more precise with exclude/include sort items on the get_users functions.

```
<ul>
<?php
    $blogusers = get_users('role=author');
    foreach ($blogusers as $user) {
        echo '<li>' . $user->user_login . '</li>';
        echo '<li>' . get_avatar($user->ID) . '</li>';
    }
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: I dont understand it... Any working template to list all user in a page with your suggested method? I need the avatars, user name and a specific user meta what links to the user profile page - and last but not least exclude specific users or a user role?t hx